# What are the privacy implications for honestly setting Git's user.name and user.email values?

Tags: git, github, privacy

Git's `user.name` and `user.email` values request your actual name and email address.

For the sake of the discussion, let's say I'd like to keep my email address private, but one day will want to open source a repository and import it to Github. Hundreds of commits/pushes later, my real name and email address, and all of my employee's info that have contributed, will be practically inseparable from the repository and public on Github. Right?

What are the long-term privacy implications, accidental or intentional, of providing truthful values for `user.name` and `user.email`?

And conversely, what are Git's functional limitations caused by providing a "username" for `user.name` and/or a false email address for `user.email`?

Comment: Though this is an interesting question, it's a discussion that's off-topic for StackOverflow (though would probably fit at Information Security: https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The year 2006 just called, they want their concerns about spam back.

Comment: I never said anything about spam. But [this GitHub article suggests it's possible](https://help.github.com/articles/keeping-your-email-address-private/).

Comment: The question was looking for real experiences from veteran Git users but it is closed now for being too broad. I'm not sure how to make it more concise, so I guess it will stay closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The privacy implications are what you make of them; if you put your personal email address as part of those commits, you're pretty much bound to them.

For instance, using `git shortlog -es` will give you a listing of both the user's name and email address as provided by what you filled out for `user.name` and `user.email`.

```
29  <Makoto's Real Name> <makoto@example.com>
 5  <Makoto's Pseudonym> <makoto@example.com>
```

The biggest thing is...if someone were to actually go through the trouble of looking my Git repository and extracting my personal email address to contact me, they could.  They'd also be able to figure out my real name.

If you personally don't want that, then don't provide truthful values to those config fields.  [GitHub even has documentation to that effect](https://github.com/blog/1580-keep-your-email-private), although if you want it to apply retroactively, you'd need to rewrite the history of your repository to make it effective.

As for the implications:  to my mind, there aren't any.  The only thing that it would *potentially* do is slow down someone trying to mail you a patch, or to be able to call you by your actual name...but if you're using GitHub, I would doubt that you'd care about the former.

Comment: Your answer sums up what I was already thinking. Your personal info travels with the repository, so if privacy is an issue then restrict the info as necessary. If it isn't, then who cares. All good, thanks.